# .dll hijacking due windows search order

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dll-injection

I have been struggling to find solution to prevent application from searching .dll files in program installation directory.

I have tried many approaches like SetDllDirectory, delaying .dll loading etc.
However my tests shows that .dlls is still searched from installation directory and only then C:/Windows

I have tested it by adding one of my own .dll that runs cmd. For example if I place DWrite.dll in installation directory in always runs cmd and then runs application.

I have few projects with same issue, one is pure C++ and other is C#, that uses some of C++ sub projects in it, this makes it even more difficult to solve.

Do anyone know proper solution for this or workaround?

Comment: why is this causing you a problem? just make sure your installer installs to a privileged folder. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications

Comment: @Jabberwocky: The question mentions `DWRITE.DLL`, that's a Microsoft DLL (DirectWrite, part of DirectX), the OS installer/Windows update placed the one in the C:\Windows\system32 directory.  Being in the OS directory isn't a problem, evidently the fake/mock/spoof DLL if one is squatting on the same name and placed in the EXE directory is the problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt I removed my comment, so your's is no longer relevant, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Have a read of [Microsoft - Secure loading of libraries to prevent DLL preloading attacks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks-d41303ec-0748-9211-f317-2edc819682e1)

Comment: +1 to @AlanBirtles - If you leave your application in an unprivileged folder, then people don't even need to hijack a DLL. They can just overwrite the application itself! You've lost the game even before it begins.